# Hide player controls on fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I implemented some custom controls for my player and I need to hide the player controls that 
appear when I move to fullscreen and show my custom controls. How can I achieve this?

```
onFullScreenClick() {
   var elem = document.getElementById('video');

   if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
     elem.requestFullscreen();
   } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
     elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
   } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
     elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
   } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
     elem.msRequestFullscreen();
   }
}

 <div
    className={'video-player'}
    onMouseEnter={this.enterVideoArea}
    onMouseLeave={this.leaveVideoArea}
  >
    <video
      ref={'video'}
      id={'video'}
      width={'640'}
      className="react-video-player"
      controls={false}
      loop
      autoPlay
      onClick={this.togglePlay}
    />
    <div
```

Comment: I imagine that as you're making the video element fullscreen, any custom controls will not appear (as they're not children of the video element). You may need to make whatever container element holds the controls fullscreen instead. (It would be good if you could expand your snippet to a working example of the problem)

Answer (score 1):

You can hide all media-controls from video tags like that

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
  display:none !important;
}
```